# firefox and select drop down menus

Tags: html, firefox

I have a select menu on my page and it appears fine in ie and chrome, but not in firefox- it appears like a horizontal item-

[image removed temporarily]

this is the code

```
<select name="times">
<option value="0" selected="">Downtown LA 10:00</option>
<option value="1">Downtown LA 12:00</option>
<option value="2">Downtown LA 14:00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Whats the css on them? What firefox version?

Comment: The link is malicious moderator should remove...

Comment: If I create a page with your select in it and view it in Firefox 3.6, it looks ok.  Like Daniel said, can you post your css and browser version?

Comment: Dunno if the link is malicious or not.  I don't get any warnings, and IIRC imageshack is legit.  But the link fails, no matter.  @Chris can you please re-up your image using the standard image upload service, [imgur](http://imgur.com/)?  [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4808214/edit), then click the little picture looking button on the toolbar.

Comment: version 3.6.12, it was the css knocking it off.. was only ff tho.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has something to do with the overflow css property, check your css for your select.  Displayed properly in firefox on Mac for me.